# Depth prediction in monocular images using NYUv2 dataset through deep learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras, conv-neural-network

Recently I am working on a research problem of obtaining depth from a monocular image using deep learning. The data set I am using is NYUv2 RGBD data set. I used the VGGNet-16 net and modified my inputs as required by the VGGnet. I used 23000 images as my initial dataset and got the RMSE error as 0.13. However, most of the research papers in this area show the RMSE to be of the range 0.6-0.9 (Although the dataset is same, but the subset of images used by each of the papers are different). One paper among them is published recently in CVPR. So I am skeptical of my approach of obtaining the RMSE. I am using keras for deep learning and theano as the back end. Below is the snippet of my RMSE code in keras:

### code 1:

```
from keras import backend as K                
def custom_rmse(y_true,y_pred):            
temp = K.mean(K.square(abs(y_pred - y_true)), axis=-1)  
    return K.sqrt(temp)
```

Some of the researh papers have mentioned of not considering the zero pixel values in the target depth image. So I also wrote the modified code for RMSE as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K                 
def custom_rmse1(y_true,y_pred):  
    ind = np.nonzero(y_true)    
    y_pred = y_pred[ind[0],ind[1], ind[2]]   
    y_true = y_true[ind[0],ind[1], ind[2]]   
    temp1 = abs(y_pred - y_true)   
    temp2 = K.square(temp1)   
    temp3 = K.mean(temp2)       
    t1 = K.sqrt(temp3)   
    return t1
```

But in both the cases, the result remained almost (0.11-0.20) same. Also I tried with different subset of images. Even I tried with 122000 images with 200 epochs. Still I got the RMSE as 0.19.

Please suggest how to proceed this problem ?

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: Are you using the 'labeled' part of the NYU V2 dataset? If so, the data has "been preprocessed to fill in missing depth labels." This would explain why your modified RMSE function gives the same loss (the zeroes have been removed from the training labels).

Comment: How did you preprocess your data? Was your depth scaled from 0-1, or 0-255?